# pointer and structure with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

Here is my problem :
I have a structure :

```
typedef struct Data_Package{
    int type;
    size_t size;
    void* data;
}Data_Package;
```

and I have a function : (Edit : Armen Tsirunyan remarks) (it is a .C function)

```
void myFunc(Data_Package* ioData) {
    ioData->data = malloc(sizeof(double));
    (ioData->data)= (double*)62.5
} //that doesn't work
```

and the main.cpp where I would like to use my function :

```
Data_Package* ioData=0;
/* some random operation that change the data,type,... */
myFunc(ioData);

stc::cout << *static_cast<double*>(ioData->data) << std::endl  //I want to display te value data (and not the address)
```

So I would like to know how to change the value data in my function and then display it in the main.cpp (I need to use pointer and data is void* because it could be double or bool or int or ...)

Thanks a lot.

Drlk.

Comment: Looks like you'd be better off using constructors and `boost:variant`.

Comment: I think I can try it but is it as precise as a defined type ? for example I receive a double from another file. If I convert it into a variant will I lose data and precision ?

Comment: What's the problem now? I see you've changed your question (and invalidated an answer). You shouldn't edit your questions this way (do not change it's contents, just add more information with EDIT section). So, what isn't working? What do you want to do?

Comment: It is still the same problem : I can't access to the ioData->data value. I have tried the solution proposed and changed the function but it still doesn't compile (problem with ioData->data = (double*)62.5 : cannot convert to a pointer).

Comment: well, you can't convert double value to pointer (which you are doing with `(double*)62.5`). @ArmenTsirunyan showed you how to do this - `*(ioData->data) = 65.5; `.Try it.

Comment: Humm you are right I shouldn't have changed the first post ... =/ *(ioData->data)=65.5 was my first try which didn't work =/

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: error : invalid use of void expression

Comment: Uhh, sorry - you should do `*static_cast<double*>(ioData->data) = 65.5;` when setting and when reading : `cout << *static_cast<double*>(ioData->data)` or assinging to variable : `double val = *static_cast<double*>(ioData->data)`

Comment: Humm I think this is what I want but when I write "**static_cast<double*>(ioData->data) = 65.5;*" the compiler tell me "error : static_cast undeclared" even if this keyword is written in blue. I think this is because I compile my function in C and I have no choice. So I have tried te C-style version ioData->data = (double*)65.5 but it "cannot convert to a pointer type".

Comment: Problem solved; thanks a lot, I have changed the project to a C++ project and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
ioData->data
```

is of type `void*`. You cannot dereference a void pointer. You should first cast it to an appropriate pointer type, in your case, double

```
cout << *static_cast<double*>(ioData->data)
```

2)

```
*(ioData->data) = 65.5;
```

Your pointer doesn't point to anything valid yet, you can't dereference it. What you probably want to do is

```
ioData->data = new double;
*static_cast<double*>(ioData->data) = 65.5
```

3)

As you can see, dealing with `void*` is ugly. Do you have any specific reason for *not* storing a `double` directly in your struct?

Comment: Humm I wil try the cast but I don't want to create the ioData in my function. I assume that the ioData exist in the main. So I won't have to make "ioData->data = new double" in my function ? I wil try the cast and declare the object in the main.cpp and I come back

Comment: I can't use the double because data can be any type (double or int or bool or whatever)

Comment: I have tried but the function doesn't compile ... =/